# Hide the empty space present on top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you click on "**Run code Snippet**" or if you check [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/golden-waves-marble-texture-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html), you can see lot of empty space in beginning, once we scroll down than only we can see the images.

I want to hide those empty space in top.

I tried `position:relative; top: some px; bottom: some px;` but it didt worked for me.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;                    
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
     // var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00,width:100, height:100}).scale(0.9);
   var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00, width: canvas.getWidth(), height: canvas.getHeight()});
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});


var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  //draw after loading
  var canvas = document.getElementById('case_canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
}

img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgNw7.png";
//^^ this will start loading the image
```

```css
/*.canvas-container {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgNw7.png") no-repeat fixed center;

  }
  */
 
 .canvas-container {
 width: 300px; height: 500px;  position: relative; -webkit-user-select: none; top:900px;
 }
 
 #canvas
 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  top:500px;
}

#file
{
 position:relative;top:900px;
}

.lower-canvas

{
 position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 500px; bottom:400px; left: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.upper-canvas {
position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 500px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none; cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input  type="file" id="file"><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="450"></canvas> 

<div class="canvas-container">
<canvas id="case_canvas" width="300" height="500" class="lower-canvas" ></canvas>
<canvas class="upper-canvas " width="300" height="500" ></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the top position for canvas container from 900 to a lower value.

**See the bellow snippet**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;                    
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
     // var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00,width:100, height:100}).scale(0.9);
   var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00, width: canvas.getWidth(), height: canvas.getHeight()});
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});


var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  //draw after loading
  var canvas = document.getElementById('case_canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
}

img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgNw7.png";
//^^ this will start loading the image
```

```css
/*.canvas-container {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgNw7.png") no-repeat fixed center;

  }
  */
 
 .canvas-container {
 width: 300px; height: 500px;  position: relative; -webkit-user-select: none; top:0px;
 }
 
 #canvas
 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  top:500px;
}

#file
{
 position:relative;top:0px;
}

.lower-canvas

{
 position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 500px; bottom:400px; left: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.upper-canvas {
position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 500px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none; cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input  type="file" id="file"><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="450"></canvas> 

<div class="canvas-container">
<canvas id="case_canvas" width="300" height="500" class="lower-canvas" ></canvas>
<canvas class="upper-canvas " width="300" height="500" ></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: more like from `900` to `0`

Comment: please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/golden-waves-marble-texture-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) , your code worked fine for image section. but still some more empty space is displaying on top.

Comment: change position for .canvas-container from relative to absolute and adjust the top & left  properties